# Return last day of quarter 1 year ago from Date()

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I am trying to calculate a value that is coordinated with the last day of last year's ending quarter. (December 31st[of the previous year], if the report was being ran in January, and March 30th[of the previous year] if it were ran on April 1st.

I tried some mix of the code below but I couldn't get it to work. Because of the possibility of the report being ran on any day of the year I couldn't just subtract a year (and I feel like there is an easier, cleaner way to perform this).

```
DateAdd("q", -4, Date())
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have it working.

```
Format
(DateAdd("s",-1,
DateAdd("q",DateDiff("q","1/1/1900",
DateAdd("yyyy",-1,Date())),"1/1/1900")),
"Short Date")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Select DateAdd(day, -1, dateadd(qq, DateDiff(qq, 0, @Date), 0))
```

Comment: Hi Vignesh, I did see that thread and tried it, also. It did not work for me. Thanks for your reply, though.